# A synonym for this idiomatic expression 'on the way'?

Tags: synonyms, alternatives

On their way Home / on the way home, they raped her.

Is there a synonym for 'on the way." I don't want to use an idiomatic expression, I have looked for possible synonyms but in vain.

Comment: I don't think *on the way [home]* really qualifies as an "idiom". All the component words are used in their normal way, and syntactically it's no different to, say, *during my voyage to America*. I can't imagine why you wouldn't want to use *on the way home*, but I suppose you might consider something like *During the journey [back]*.

Comment: Why do you not want to use an idiomatic expression? What is it you understand by the word "idiomatic"?

Comment: Jesus Christ. That sentence was unexpectedly horrible!

Comment: @Mark Particularly as it implies that the guys were just headed home, saw a lady, and said... hey... want to commit rape?  I'm guessing that the OP **means** "on **her** way home, she was raped." but, as is, it is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the 0P doesn't want to use the phrase "on the way", which is so natural and commonly used. Nevertheless, the following are some alternatives he may like to use, depending on the context:

1. While they were going home.
2. While they were walking home.
3. While they were traveling home.
4. While they were driving home.
5. While they were heading home.
6. While they were making their way home.

Answer (score 0):

*On the way [to] X* means *while traveling [to] X* - any word that means *to travel* can be substituted (i.e. *while walking home,* etc.)